# How to make a HTTP PUT request?

Tags: c#, http, rest

What is the best way to compose a rest PUT request in C#?

The request has to also send an object not present in the URI.

Comment: PUT is HTTP. REST is an architecture, not a protocol.

Comment: yes but in this particular question i am using http in a specific scenario ie rest...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
using(var client = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
    client.UploadData(address,"PUT",data);
}
```

Comment: I used a slightly different approach but this worked nicely. Thanks

Comment: Mind explaining how to add an oauth header to this?

Comment: @toing_toing you add headers via `client.Headers.Add(...);`. As for what the name/value should be - you'll have to research that yourself

Comment: When using this solution with a string for post data. I don't see it updating on the website. byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData); Is how I am creating the Byte Array.

Comment: @DotNetProgrammer what the site does with it is up to the site

Comment: @DotNet Programmer Why do you call data for a PUT request "post data"?

Comment: @TheincredibleJan I don't presume to speak for them, but: it conveys sufficient intent to be useful; sure, we could talk about the "http request body", but: I would absolutely know what they mean by "post data" in the context of a PUT request, so: job done

Answer (score 35):

My Final Approach:

```
    public void PutObject(string postUrl, object payload)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            if (payload !=null)
            {
                request.ContentLength = Size(payload);
                Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                Serialize(dataStream,payload);
                dataStream.Close();
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string returnString = response.StatusCode.ToString();
        }

public void Serialize(Stream output, object input)
            {
                var ser = new DataContractSerializer(input.GetType());
                ser.WriteObject(output, input);
            }
```

Comment: What is Size(payload) ? It is not defined.

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var values = string.Format("Name={0}&Family={1}&Id={2}", NameToUpdateTextBox.Text, FamilyToUpdateTextBox.Text, IdToUpdateTextBox.Text);
            var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(values);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://localhost:51436/api/employees"));
            request.Method = "PUT";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            var response =  (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                UpdateResponseLabel.Text = "Update completed";
            else
                UpdateResponseLabel.Text = "Error in update";
        }
```

Comment: Hi there. I was about to up-vote this when I noticed the following line: `var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(values);`. Is there a specific reason why you are converting Unicode into 7 bit ASCII? That will certainly lose any non-US English characters. Unless that would somehow break the receiving system, I would think that you should instead be using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(values)`. At the very least you should have a comment in the code warning readers who might be copying it that they most likely should replace `ASCII` with `UTF8` on that line. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

How to use PUT method using WebRequest.

```
    //JsonResultModel class
    public class JsonResultModel
    {
       public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
       public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
       public string Results { get; set; }
    }
    // HTTP_PUT Function
    public static JsonResultModel HTTP_PUT(string Url, string Data)
    {
        JsonResultModel model = new JsonResultModel();
        string Out = String.Empty;
        string Error = String.Empty;
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Url);

        try
        {
            req.Method = "PUT";
            req.Timeout = 100000;
            req.ContentType = "application/json";
            byte[] sentData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data);
            req.ContentLength = sentData.Length;

            using (System.IO.Stream sendStream = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                sendStream.Write(sentData, 0, sentData.Length);
                sendStream.Close();

            }

            System.Net.WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream ReceiveStream = res.GetResponseStream();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new 
            System.IO.StreamReader(ReceiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {

                Char[] read = new Char[256];
                int count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);

                while (count > 0)
                {
                    String str = new String(read, 0, count);
                    Out += str;
                    count = sr.Read(read, 0, 256);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Error = string.Format("HTTP_ERROR :: The second HttpWebRequest object has raised an Argument Exception as 'Connection' Property is set to 'Close' :: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Error = string.Format("HTTP_ERROR :: WebException raised! :: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error = string.Format("HTTP_ERROR :: Exception raised! :: {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        model.Results = Out;
        model.ErrorMessage = Error;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Out))
        {
            model.IsSuccess = true;
        }
        return model;
    }
```