# How to get pdf from iPhone to .net c# website?

Tags: c#, .net, ios, pdf, ios6

Right now, I have a pdf being created in my iphone app. I'm using http requests to send a bunch of data to my website and then save that info in a database. Is there a way to send this pdf to the website and save it to the include folder in the website's file system? The website is built in .net and c#.

I know how to create a page on the website where people can upload a file and then save that to the file system but I don't know how to get it from ios to the website. Thanks for any advice.

Edit: The other option would to be sending just an image to the website for the same purpose if that's easier.

Edit: I guess I should specify that the app is being built in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more searching around and going through different ideas, this is what I ended up doing. I found this great tutorial on uploading to a php page so I just added that to my website and save the image to the file system, then I can pull it from there with the c# code.

http://objective-c.wonderhowto.com/how-to/upload-image-website-from-apple-ios-application-333979/

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). Makes uploading a breeze.
(Asuming the application is written in Objective-C).

Example: [Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Comment: That looks good, how would I handle that in the c# code then? I am using Request["id"] to take in url parameters right now for the simple text data.

Answer (score 0):

If the iPhone App is using MonoTouch (C# and .Net Framework), take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140674/create-a-http-put-request-programmatically-with-c-sharp).