# How do I configure an HttpClient for an api put unit test?

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I am new to api web services. I am working on a web service that should update a database table. I have decided to use put, but I am having trouble testing with my unit test.

**CONTROLLER**

```
static readonly ICarsRepository repository = new CarsRepository();

public void PutRejectRecord(int carId, int statusId)
{
    if (!repository.RejectRecord(carId, statusId))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

**MODEL**

```
public class CarsRepository : ICarsRepository
{
    public bool RejectRecord(int carId, int statusId)
    { ... }
```

I have been searching for a solution to no avail. I have tried but failed using

```
string uri = "api/Cars/Approve/{id}/{approveStatus}";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent("2"));
```

which makes no sense.

How do I set the HttpClient to point to 'PUT api/Cars/Approve/{id}/{approveStatus}'? I am trying to get this right and I am yet to have the lightbulb moment which is frustrating... Please help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like:

1) You're using C#, correct?  With MVC3 or 4, correct?

2) You have a pre-existing REST web service (you're not writing the service yourself, correct)?

3) All you want to do is get your C# program to talk to the service, correct?

Here are a few links:

- [How to make a HTTP PUT request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140674/how-to-make-a-http-put-request)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426769/Creating-a-REST-service-using-ASP-NET-Web-API
- http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api